# Why is my RXJS next function getting called before the $digest cycle ends, and how can I wait?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

I have the following (In Coffeescript)

```
beforeEach "We should see the list changed event", (done) ->
    constructorSubscription = importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
        # Expects
        constructorSubscription.unsubscribe()
        done()
    doSomething()    
    $rootScope.$apply()
it "Actual Test", (done) ->
    importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
        # Expect conditions
        done()
    doSomethingElse()
    $rootScope.$apply()
```

When this test runs it gets to the $rootScope.apply and belly aches

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest`

This is because the digest cycle calls the Subject's next method before it is completely done running. This leaves the $digest cycle running even after done is called. I can fix this by adding setTimeout to done...

`setTimeout -> done()`

As long as the digest doesn't take longer than the timeout it works but this is really hacky.

Is there an event I can key off of to tell me when the digest is complete?

***ADDITIONAL INFO***

**Other Info**

The code that is being tested is an RXJS subject so doSomething is calling something like this...

```
@subject = new window.Rx.Subject()
...
onListChanged: => 
    @subject.filter (message)=> # filter logic
...
doSomething: => 
    @subject.next someValue
doSomethingElse: => 
    @subject.next otherValue
```

If I remove the $apply then I get a timeout error

I also tried this but it didn't work

```
$timeout -> $rootScope.$apply()
$timeout.flush()
```

But it didn't help

**Update**

I tried this per the answer and it didn't get me anywhere

```
beforeEach "We should see the list changed event", (done) ->
    constructorSubscription = importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
        # Expects
        constructorSubscription.unsubscribe()
        done()

    $rootScope.$apply ->
        doSomething() 
it "Actual Test", (done) ->
    importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
        # Expect conditions
        done()
    $rootScope.$apply ->
        doSomethingElse()
```

But it still says the digest cycle is running

I also tried

```
beforeEach "We should see the list changed event", (done) ->
    doSomething() 
    $rootScope.$apply -> 
        constructorSubscription = importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
            # Expects
            constructorSubscription.unsubscribe()
            done()

it "Actual Test", (done) ->        
    doSomethingElse()
    $rootScope.$apply ->
        importList.onListChanged().subscribe ->
            # Expect conditions
            done()
```

This also doesn't work and fails with the same digest in progress error

Next I tried this...

```
$rootScope.$apply -> done();
```

Again I see the same results.

**For those who haven't used CS extensively**

```
$rootScope.$apply ->
    doSomethingElse()
```

compiles to

```
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
    return doSomethingElse();
});
```

whereas

```
$rootScope.$apply (->
    doSomethingElse())
```

compiles to

```
$rootScope.$apply((function() {
    return doSomethingElse();
 }));
```

So they are the same

I am noticing that when I call apply the first time, beginPhase is called but never clear phase. Trying to figure out why now.

Answer (score -1):

Lightning version: Angular doesn't check every value on every digest. It only know what has changed if the changes happen inside of a $apply(). Mostly this is hidden as it happens behind the scenes when using standard angular directives/controllers and just binding data as usual. After $apply is done then a digest happens. Since these changes can trigger other things that are being watched then the digest will be run multiple times per cycle. The error you're seeing is because you are call $apply which calls $digest while a digest cycle is already in progress.

If change is made from an outside source, i.e a callback from a third party, angular doesn't know about it. You're correct that you need to use $apply, however you should pass it a function which it can execute in proper time.

I don't know coffee script syntax but I think this javascript example should show the fix.

```
importList.onchange = function(){//callback for onchange
    $scope.$apply(function(){ //use $apply an pass in function
        constructorSubscription.unsubscribe();
        done();
        doSomething() ;
    });
};
```

<del>EDIT: There's errors in the coffeescript changes you made to implement the above.</del>

In Particular, this

```
$rootScope.$apply ->
    doSomethingElse()
```

should be

```
$rootScope.$apply (->
    doSomethingElse())
```

EDIt i was wrong here with specific syntax that is wrong

[Here's a full working example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CDdCknkANsOvC7SVNuyW?p=preview)

Note that setInterval is outside of angular so it simulates your example above. Compared to [This Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDOKzHcCD9X0RSpqSMlT?p=preview) which, if you open your console, you can see it properly change=ing the value but doesnt use $apply.

Comment: I can't change the declaration of onchange because it is in my code, and the code shouldn't be handling the applies it should let Angular deal with that if needed. I only need to mess with apply in tests. So I need to declare my subscription before I call apply, so how would I wrap that?

Comment: yeah I don't think this will work because I can't wrap my it statement in the apply which is I think what this would require.

Comment: Sorry man but I think I am going to have to down vote this answer since I knew all this and it isn't solving any of the issue, I will wait a bit till you respond

Comment: Yeah your coffeescript is incorrect. You need to pass the function to be applied INTO the apply. Currently you set it as the return parameter. Also this might be intentional but you apply the doSomething() after you set your callbacks, not when they actually get triggered. i.e like $rootScope.$apply(doSomethingElse()) not $rootScope.$apply ->
        doSomethingElse()

Comment: Ok I updated answer with full working demo in coffeescript.

Comment: Those coffeescripts are the same I compiled both and the only diff is the function is wrapped in a paren which doesn't matter

Comment: Also that plunker doesn't solve the problem for jasmine like is asked. Of Course apply works like that it is documented that way. I need to know why even when I call it that way the digest cycle is still running in the next jasmine step.

Comment: So the main reason I thumbs downed this was because the function you pass to apply gets called before the digest. I needed to know how to wait till after the digest cycle. Doing apply and passing a function won't cause that function to wait till the digest cycle is over according to the angular code